# Prove if $P(A | B^c) = P(A | B)$ then the events A and B are independent.

Tags: probability

So I've started by saying that since $P(A | B^c) = P(A | B)$ we know that $\frac{P(A \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. However I'm not sure where to go from there. Any help would be great!

Comment: Hint: $P(A) = P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c)+P(A\mid B)P(B)$

Comment: How do you define "the events $A$ and $B$ are independent" ?

Comment: I define it as $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: @mconn7 Henry's comment was a Socratic question.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{P(A \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} =\frac{P(A) -P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)}= \frac{P(A \cap B)} {P(B)}$$ now $$(P(A) -P(A\cap B))P(B)=P(A \cap B)(1-P(B))$$ thus
$P(A)P(B)-\color{red}{P(A\cap B)P(B)}=P(A \cap B)-\color{red}{P(A\cap B)P(B)}$ so
$P(A)P(B)=P(A \cap B) $ hence $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: So I understand everything here except how you got $P(A-B)$. Where does that come from?

Comment: dear $A \cap B^c=A-B$ thus $p(A \cap B^c)=p(A-B)$

Comment: @mconn7 $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$ so $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$. Here $A-B$ is only a different notation of $A\cap B^c$ and it is not really functional in this proof.

Comment: @drhab I did :) .

Comment: Yes, and I kept my promise.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** By the Total Probability Theorem: $\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf P(A\mid B^c)\,\mathsf P(B^c)+\mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B)$

Then since: $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\mathsf P(A\mid B^c)$ ...

Answer (score 1):

The defining relation is: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$$

You could also write: $$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ but that asks for an apart treatment of the special case $P(B)=0$.

Let's say that $P(A\mid B)=c=P(A\mid B^c)$.

Then:

$$P(A)=P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c)=cP(B)+cP(B^c)=c=P(A\mid B)$$

So: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)=P(A)P(B)$$